# JS command(s) to store constant bookmarklet variables in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, variables, bookmarklet

**Storing constant bookmarklet variables for IE8/9?**

In Firefox you can permanently save (cross-domain) constant variables to the browser to be written/accessed via bookmarklets (*i.e. not just cookie/session level*) through the following JS:

`var prefManager = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].`
`getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);`
`prefManager.setCharPref("extensions.ename.var_name", var_value);`

In Chrome you can do:

`window.localStorage.setItem('var_name', var_value);`

Does anyone know what the equivalent command is for Internet Explorer please? (To enable a JS bookmarklet to permanently save an approved user request id.)

Comment: `while(!!ActiveXObject) { alert("Download a real browser"); }`

Comment: I just need to save a new variable.. hopefully doable.

Comment: @Robert No need for `!!`. The header of the while statement is coerced to boolean automatically, so you don't need to cast it.

Comment: but any ideas on the question please? :)

Comment: @Don So, in Chrome you use localStorage. Why aren't you using localStorage in Firefox, too?

Comment: @Don localStorage also works in IE8 http://diveintohtml5.org/storage.html

Comment: @Šime Vidas I just went with the method the Mozilla directory listed. Ah, that works for IE too? That'd be perfect then, thank you for the tip. So the localStorage commands can be used for IE exactly as they are in Chrome then? I'll check out the link now! :D

Comment: @Šime Vidas Ah yes, I've had a read up and that is exactly what I was after. I hadn't realised IE8+ now supports it. Thank you ever so much for the info! :)